# PowerShell: Extract specific files/folders from a zipped archive

Tags: powershell, zip, archive, unzip

Say `foo.zip` contains:

```
a
b
c
|- c1.exe 
|- c2.dll 
|- c3.dll
```

where `a, b, c` are folders.

If I

```
Expand-Archive .\foo.zip -DestinationPath foo
```

all files/folders in `foo.zip` are extracted.
I would like to extract only the `c` folder.

Comment: I have same question... all answers below are ridiculously complex.  MS why you hate me?

Answer (score 18):

try this

```
Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

#extract list entries for dir myzipdir/c/ into myzipdir.zip
$zip = [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead("c:\temp\myzipdir.zip")
$entries=$zip.Entries | where {$_.FullName -like 'myzipdir/c/*' -and $_.FullName -ne 'myzipdir/c/'} 

#create dir for result of extraction
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "c:\temp\c" -Force

#extraction
$entries | foreach {[IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile( $_, "c:\temp\c\" + $_.Name) }

#free object
$zip.Dispose()
```

Comment: This worked like a charm and should be accepted. System.IO is not an "external library". It's .NET

Comment: You can use following regex to filter entries: `$zip.Entries | Where-Object { $_ -match 'myzipdir/c/+.' }`

Answer (score 2):

This one does not use external libraries:

```
$shell= New-Object -Com Shell.Application 
$shell.NameSpace("$(resolve-path foo.zip)").Items() | where Name -eq "c" | ? {
    $shell.NameSpace("$PWD").copyhere($_) }
```

Perhaps it can be simplified a bit.

Comment: It did't work for me. It always returned empty result. How can I just show the content of the zip file? $i = $shell.Namespace("$(resolve-path .\myarc.zip)") then $i gets me a single object not enumeratable; I know that the path is right because when it's not right it returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works for me. Of Course, you will need to edit the code to fit your objective

```
$results =@()

foreach ($p in $Path)
{


$shell = new-object -Comobject shell.application
$fileName = $p
$zip = $shell.namespace("$filename")

$Results +=  $zip.items()| where-object { $_.Name -like "*C*" -or  $_.Name -like 
"*b*"  }
}
foreach($item in $Results )
{

$shell.namespace($dest).copyhere($item)
}
```